# git submodule "--remote" results in (new commits)

Tags: git, git-submodules

How do I prevent git status from showing submodule locked to specific submodule branch as a change after update?

I added a git submodule using a specific branch:

```
git submodule add -b feature/special git@.../buildenv.git env
git commit -a -m "added submodule locked to special feature"
git push
```

All was good until someone committed to the submodule and pushed
Now, when I update the submodule I see new commits messages from status

```
git submodule update --remote --recursive --init
git diff

index b45bfd8..2334b1f 160000
--- a/env
+++ b/env
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit b45bfd8f498a4d86a9586e1a4b1a6194052274b0
+Subproject commit 2334b1faa019c28c6fe75cef94fd94d847593c37
```

Answer (score 0):

That is what you asked for when you (1) specified `-b feature/special` and then (2) used `update --remote`.  (Both are required for this action, though it's the `update --remote` part that triggers the actual updating, and you can go in and add, remove, or adjust the `-b` setting before the `update --remote`—but normally you would not, and I assume you did not.)

Since I don't use submodules (being way too familiar with their alternative name, "sob-modules" :-) although they certainly have improved recently) I do not really want to give advice on the "right way" to do this.  I can, however, explain the underlying mechanism and how all this rather complicated Jenga-ish structure came about.

Essentially, a submodule is just a simple pairing:

- My superproject X is in a repository.  It has commits X1, X2, ..., X11.
- To use these commits, you also need a separate repository Y...

  - I tested my superproject X at commit X1, X2, X3, and so on, using the other repository at commit Y20, so you must and will get commit Y20 and only ever commit Y20.
  - Oh wait, I just updated and re-tested my superproject at new commit X12 using the other repository at commit Y47, so you must and will get commit Y47 and only ever commit Y47 (for my commit X12; and Y20 for all my earlier commits).

In other words, the pairing is *by commit ID in your superproject*: for every commit in your superproject, you list the SHA-1 ID of the (single) commit in the subproject.

That is fine for totally-static subprojects, but eventually we build things with subprojects that actually have and use branches, rather than just sticking with version 2.0 (commit Y20) forever.  So, since I last used it, git now has the ability to associate a branch name with a subproject.

You must, however, still explicitly tell git that *now* is the time to update the subproject: "please go into my subproject, find the latest commit on branch `feature/special`, and record its SHA-1 ID in my superproject."  That is what `git submodule update --remote` does (with several extra mode options) when you have set that submodule up with `-b`.

At this point it is your job to test the whole thing and make sure that it all works.  If it *does* all work, you can then make a new commit in your superproject.  This new commit will record the new ID that you see in your `git diff` output.  The old subproject ID (which I was calling Y20 above) is `b45bfd8f498a4d86a9586e1a4b1a6194052274b0` and the new one (which I was calling Y47 above) is now `2334b1faa019c28c6fe75cef94fd94d847593c37`, which is what you see in your `git diff`.

To add the new subproject ID to the superproject (so that you can commit it now that it is tested and known to work), use `git add` on the gitlink that `git diff` is showing you, which in this case is `env`.  Watch out here, I used to get bitten by an annoyance all the time:

```
$ git add env    # now ready to commit
```

(*AVOID the trailing slash in* `git add env/` *as this adds the contents of the entire submodule into the superproject!*).  It is possible that the annoyance with the trailing slash is fixed (git should notice that it is not possible to have both a gitlink entry `foo` and files/trees named `foo/anything`).

Comment: it seems that the -b results in branch HEAD @ time of add stored in place of branch.  Subsequent updates --remote pull down the later HEAD for branch resulting in the difference.  By adding ignore=all the difference vanishes.   I don't want my users working in that directory as I use it to offer standard buildenv to multiple branches.  so I'm good with that

Comment: That's not quite the right way to think about it: it's not that `-b` "stores HEAD-at-time-of-add *in place of* branch", but rather that *all* submodules *always* record *only* a commit ID.  Meanwhile `-b` *also* records, separately, an "intent to auto-update to latest when you request `--update`".  (Which makes sense given the name `--update`...)  According to gitmodules(5), setting `submodule.<name>.ignore=all` just makes the update *not show in your diff*, but you will still get a new (updated) submodule, which seems a bit dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Use of -b grabs  HEAD commit id from submodule and stores it in client branch.  Subsequent commits to submodule result in a new HEAD.  After updating submodule to new branch HEAD we see difference between stored original and new head.

Adding  ignore = all  to .gitmodules hides this from branch users but may not be appropriate in all cases.